# resolve merge conflicts without manually editing each file

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm new to Git and I'm trying to find a quicker way to resolve merge conflicts. Say I tried to merge a branch to master and I get merge conflicts for some of the files.

```
Changes to be committed:

    modified:   ...

Unmerged paths:
   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   ...
```

Git goes into each of the both modified files and adds conflict-resolution markers right? (<<<<<<< this stuff). Normally I would go into the files and manually change them but in this case they are all bin files and not too relevant to my program working. Is there a way I can just stage all the `modified` files and specify that I want all the `unmodified` files to remain the way they were in the `master` before the merge. (basically disregard the changes from the branch to those files). Thanks

Comment: What's the point of keeping the files tracked then?

Comment: you have a point. My project is over a thousand files so when I initialized I just did `git add .` without realizing that it might cause merge conflicts not worth keeping track of. I will remove them from the repository thanks. But in the case they were useful is there any way I can go a merge of specific files only?

Comment: Also: consider adding those files - or a pattern matching them - to your .gitignore. This will keep them from being tracked at all; better in the long run if they aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes I just discovered this functionality and I've created the file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must find the copy of the file you wish to use, check it out, stage changes, and then commit. For example:

```
git log 

(find out we want the file from commit ac3422d4ceba793ff9fd3df81159d23111a760e2)

git checkout ac3422d4ceba793ff9fd3df81159d23111a760e2 file/to/fix.txt
git add file/to/fix.txt
git commit -m "success!!"
```

What this does is:

- replace the file with the one from the specified commit
- stage the change *and* mark the merge conflict on the file as resolved
- commit the change/merge

Answer (score 0):

When merging, you can specify a "strategy". From `git help merge`:

> ours
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively
>              ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.
>              Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.